# backbone model is only returning and object, or JSON {readyState : 1}

Tags: jquery, json, backbone.js

I am still learning backbone and building my first app at the same time, so any help to get the ball rolling again would be awesome.

First, all i am trying to do it is get the proper response from the backbone. I am 100% sure that the server is sending me pure JSON, as I can check it in the browser via a URL. Same url as the `urlRoot` in my code, its just saved in a var.

I had this *kind of* working before but i was getting a JSON response through a collection(it look okay), which i later found was not the best, and I would rather get data through models. But I can not seem to get the same return from the server using models.

Here is my code:
Model:

```
        var CalendarDay = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
  urlRoot: daysURL      
});

var calendarItem = new CalendarDay();
```

Shouldn't I just be able to do this `console.log(calendarItem.fetch())` and get the correct JSON response?

This is what my console shows:
[image]

What i want is the "responseText" potion only...

This also means that using `calendarItem.get(*****)` doesnt work.

Any ideas ladies/gents?

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the screenshot is the jqXHR object returned by `fetch`. This object represents the asynchronous ajax call rather than the response text.

The responseText is a list rather than a single object. So the `calendarItem` will contain the list rather than the item attributes. Try a `console.log` on `calendarItem.attributes` (after waiting for `fetch` to finish.)

If you only want to fetch on item you can use a function as the url property of your model - then you can pass an ID to the model and `.url()` returns the resource location for that calendar item.

Comment: a better question is how do i start using this object I have .fetch() with the normal backbone get() and set().

Comment: What changes did you make? Is it `calendarItem.attributes` that's empty?