# Backbone fetch and working with the jqXHR object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, backbone.js, jqxhr

I'm working on a new application using Backbone and don't have the backend APIs written yet so I am trying work with a JSON data file local to my project. I set its location as the urlRoot and am able to fetch it and receive the jqXHR object back. But, I am not sure how to interact with the responseText (assuming that's what I need based on the console.log output of the object).

This is the closest question I've found to mine but it wasn't closed with a final answer: [backbone model is only returning and object, or JSON {readyState : 1}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012878/backbone-model-is-only-returning-and-object-or-json-readystate-1)

```
var JobListings = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: 'scripts/app/data/listings.json'
});

// Instantiate the model
var jobListings = new JobListings();

console.log(jobListings.fetch()); // Returns jqXHR object
console.log(jobListings.attributes); // Returns empty object
```

How do I get at my JSON data? Also, it should be in a model and not a collection right? I am a bit fuzzy as to the role of collections based on other developers use of them. I thought models contain data and collections were sets of models.

My goal was to build two models for the data. One takes in the dirty JSON that needs to be cleaned up and the second being my outputted clean data for use by the application. Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:

A snippet of my JSON... I'm still not having luck on how to get at my data. I'm sure I don't have to get to a view to see my data before hand.

```
[
  {
    "jobId": "1",
    "applyUrl": "http://google.com",
    "title": "President of the World",
    "trackingCode": "1",
    "jobDescription": "Stuff",
    "requiredSkills": "Stuff",
    "requiredExperience": [],
    "postingDate": "2013-07-12T11:07:50Z",
    "jobLocation": {
      "countryCode": "US",
      "region": "California",
      "municipality": "Santa Monica"
    },
    "category": "Life",
    "businessUnit": [],
    "positionType": "Full-Time"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

['Backbone.Model'](http://backbonejs.org/#Model) contains data

['Backbone.Collection'](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) were set of models. Like you can define it as in below:

```
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Book
});
```

You normally won't work with jqXHR directly.
Once data is fetched, you can access it "field by field" (or attribute-by-attribute) using [get](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get) operation:

```
note.get("title")
```

You can edit the data using the [set](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) operation:

```
note.set({title: "March 20", content: "In his eyes she eclipses..."});
book.set("title", "A Scandal in Bohemia");
```

You can return a copy of the data (called attributes) using [toJSON](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) operation

Also Backbone will track if data is dirty or not by using [hasChanged](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-hasChanged)

Comment: Thanks, I understand from a high level about accessing the data but I have still not been successful.

Comment: If you post a repro on github to show the problem that you are facing, I can take a look.

Comment: That's really nice of you, I appreciate that. I have to make some edits to make this public facing but I will push up another version of the repo to my Git shortly. https://github.com/dandigangi

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, JobListing will be a model with job listing data. JobListings would be a collection of all JobListing models:

```
var JobListing = Backbone.Model.extend();

var JobListings = Backbone.Collection.extend({,
  model: JobListing,
  url: 'scripts/app/data/listings.json',
  parse: function(data) {
     // Not sure about your json structure, but you could do the following
     // Do your cleanup here
     return data.joblistings;
  }
});

// Instantiate the collection
var jobListings = new JobListings();

var req = jobListings.fetch();

req.done(function() {
  // contains all job listings
  console.log(jobListings.models);
});
```

Comment: I think I might be missing a core understanding of a lot of this. In the parsing function, does data already refer to my local file? And what does the .jobListings refer to if the collection hasn't been instantiated yet? Or, in the console.log(jobListings.models), what does models refer to? Is that a Backbone keyword for accessing the collection's model(s)?

Comment: The parse function is used to allow you to manipulate your json data. So if your data files is not just returning joblistings, but maybe some meta info, you can manipulate what exactly you want your collection to return. 'The function is passed the raw response object, and should return the array of model attributes to be added to the collection'. The collection object holds your models, and yes collection.models is a convenience method for accessing your models. jobListings instantiates your collection. jobListings.fetch() populates your collection with models returned by your parse function.